# Using NVL with JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to display 2 values in table but only Student 301 is displayed. Student 102 doesn't received any grades. I joined two tables. Here's my query. Thanks for your help

```sql
SELECT g.student_id, NVL(g.numeric_grade, 0) AS numeric_grade, e.enrollment_date
  FROM grade_info g
  JOIN enrollment_info e 
    ON g.student_id = e.student_id
 WHERE g.student_id IN (102, 301)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, both students are in `enrollment_info`.  If so, you can use:

```
SELECT e.student_id, NVL(g.numeric_grade, 0) AS numeric_grade, e.enrollment_date
FROM enrollment_info e LEFT JOIN
     grade_info g
     ON e.student_id = g.student_id
WHERE e.student_id IN (102, 301);
```

Note the use of `LEFT JOIN`.  The table where you want to keep all the rows comes first.  You can filter on this table in the `WHERE` clause.  Although not part of this question, filters on subsequent tables (when using `LEFT JOIN`) should be in the `ON` clause.

Also note the use of meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  Arbitrary letters make the query much harder to follow -- and make it easy to make mistakes.

If both students are not in enrollment info, then you need to start with them using a derived table of some sort.  That would look like:

```
SELECT s.student_id, COALESCE(g.numeric_grade, 0) AS numeric_grade, e.enrollment_date
FROM (SELECT 102 as student_id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 301 as student_id FROM DUAL
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     enrollment_info e
     ON e.student_id = s.student_id LEFT JOIN
     grade_info g
     ON g.student_id = s.student_id;
```

This also uses `COALESCE()` instead of `NVL()` because `COALESCE()` is the Standard SQL function for replacing `NULL` values.

Answer (score 2):

You did not post your table structure, but I am pretty sure that you need to change your join to be an [OUTER join](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/joins/oracle-left-outer-join.php).  Try this:

```
SELECT a.student_id, NVL(a.numeric_grade, 0) AS numeric_grade, b.enrollment_date
FROM enrollment_info b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  grade_info a
ON a.student_id = b.student_id
WHERE a.student_id IN (102, 301)
```

The NVL function only applies to the data in the rows that are already fetched. A null column value is different than a missing row.